# AWS HTTPS requests not working on EC2 Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https, amazon-elb, targeting

I have an EC2 instance which is running an NodeJS Web-app and I want to enable HTTPS traffic to my instance. I purchased a domain name from AWS and requested an SSL Certificate.

I have also created a Target group which should redirect the traffic to HTTP port 3000 because my node app is running on port 3000.

[image]

I created a Load Balancer which should Listen to the HTTPS traffic and redirect it to the Target group.

[image]

It seems to work fine but when I click on the DNS name to see whether it is working or not, I can't connect to the server. Do you know what might be the issue.

[image]

I have checked and my EC2 instance has opened HTTPS request, so that should't be the issue.[image]

Comment: Does the security group of the load balancer allow inbound https (443) traffic from your client ip?

Comment: How can I check that?

Comment: See the *update the associated security group* section here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-update-security-groups.html

Comment: What are the listener rules that you use?

Comment: I forward the traffic to port 3000

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details. For example you got your domain from R53 and SSL from ACM. Did you create alias record in R53 to point to the ALB? Please provide all relevant details of your setup, including full setup of your listener rules, how do you test the connections, and more.

Comment: The listener rules are forwarding the traffic to Https, which you can see on the first image. It redirects the traffic to HTTP Port 3000. And yes I allow inside the security group an https traffic, you can see that on the last image. Can you tell me what else you need to check so that I can send you a photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows you use ACM and application load balancer so your ALB terminates SSL. If so make sure:

- Your load balancer has a security group allowing inbound 443 from internet and outbound 3000 to your EC2 instance
- Your EC2 instance hosting your node app has a security group allowing inbound 3000 from ALB

Traffic between ALB and instance is HTTP. SSL is terminated on the ALB, so after the ALB (inside your VPC) you're http only.